# Parallel Bubble Sort is blocked

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, parallel-processing, openmp

My OpenMP program blocks on the first "for" loop of the following code, without any apparent reason.
I'm simply trying to parallelize a Bubble Sort.

Below is a complete code reproducing the issue :

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

static int N_THREADS;
#define CHUNK_SIZE (size/N_THREADS)

void
parallel_bubble_sort(uint64_t *T, const uint64_t size)
{
    register bool swapped;
    register uint64_t swap;
    register int i,j;

    #pragma omp parallel private(swap,i,j)
    do {
        swapped = false;

        #pragma omp for schedule(static) reduction(||:swapped)
        for (j=0; j<N_THREADS; j++)
        for (i=j*CHUNK_SIZE+1; i<=(j+1)*CHUNK_SIZE-1; i++)
        if (T[i-1] > T[i]) {
            swap = T[i-1];
            T[i-1] = T[i];
            T[i] = swap;
            swapped = true;
        }

        #pragma omp for schedule(static) reduction(||:swapped)
        for (i=CHUNK_SIZE-1; i<size-CHUNK_SIZE; i+=CHUNK_SIZE)
        if (T[i] > T[i+1]) {
            swap = T[i];
            T[i] = T[i+1];
            T[i+1] = swap;
            swapped = true;
        }
    } while(swapped);
}

int main ()
{
    uint64_t i;
    uint64_t N = 1024;
    N_THREADS = omp_get_max_threads();

    uint64_t *X = (uint64_t *) malloc(N * sizeof(uint64_t));
    for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) X[i] = N-i;

    parallel_bubble_sort(X, N);
    free(X);
}
```

Some additional context:

- T* is a pointer to an array of type uint64_t
- size is the size of the array
- CHUNK_SIZE is simply size/NUM_THREADS (which is also the default chunk size value OpenMP uses in the static scheduling mode, so I should get the same behavior if I remove this from the clause)

Regarding the logic behind the code:

- In the first loop, I divide my array into chunks, and I propagate bubbles separately without overlap between threads
- In the second loop, I make sure the bubbles propagate at the borders

More details about the issue I have while executing:

- My program is stuck on the first "for" loop. I have localized where the program blocks using #pragma omp single, and a simple print statement.

Comment: *Ca ! C'est de la merde !* RIP JPC https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G4iIIatxTH8

Comment: What happens if you move the declarations of `i` and `swapped` to within the `j` for loop (so that they are declared on each thread instead of relying on private)?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm `swapped` cannot be declared just in the `j` for loop since it is used by the do-while loop. @JeanPierreCoffe `swapped` is not protected and is set to `false` by multiple threads in parallel without any barrier. Thus, it can be set to `false` while other threads are executing the `j` loop which probably cause a race condition.

Comment: Oops - I meant `swap`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Moving the declarations does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the deadlock is a data race condition in your outermost loop:

```
do {
   swapped = false;  // <--- here
   ...
} while(swapped);    // <--- here
```

The race happens becase there is no guarantee that all threads will arrive at the instruction implementing the `while(swapped)` conditional at the same time. Imagine you have two threads. Thread 0 finishes the second parallel loop, sees that `swapped` is `true`, passes through the loop conditional and then starts again the loop body by setting `swapped` to `false`. If thread 1 reaches the the conditional *before* thread 0 was able to set `swapped` to `false`, it too will start a new iteration. But if arrives a bit too late, `swapped` will be `false` and the loop will terminate. As a result, thread 1 will not join the parallel loop and thread 0 will forever wait at the implicit synchronisation barrier.

The solution is to make sure that all threads have a consistent view of what the value of `swapped` is when they make a decision whether to start a new iteration or not. The simplest solution is to insert a barrier right before setting `swapped` to `false`:

```
do {
   #pragma omp barrier
   swapped = false;
   ...
} while(swapped);
```

Also, having all threads reset `swapped` is not really necessary and it may possibly (not sure about it) go against the OpenMP spec that forbids concurrent access to the original variable before the reduction is complete. I'm not sure if it applies to modifications *before* the reduction region (as I wasn't sure [a couple of years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22942434/1374437)) and there was a paragraph deleted from the OpenMP 4.5 spec regarding concurrent access, but just to be safe, I'd give the assingment the `single` treatment:

```
do {
   #pragma omp barrier
   #pragma omp single
   swapped = false;
   ...
} while(swapped);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Indeed, I loop for j<N_THREADS, which I will change for improved clarity.
Yes, adding CHUNK_SIZE in the schedule clause makes no sense - this was a residual from an earlier version.

I have corrected my program by removing the "CHUNK_SIZE" from the schedule clause.
As you can see, there is no "single" construct anywhere in the loop. The complete contents of the loop are in my initial post.

Making the change that you suggested does not unlock the program, it still blocks on the first iteration.

Comment: @Jean-PierreCoffe do you have a self-contained fully-functional code that reproduces the problem? What happens if you remove the `register` keywords? Also, what OS and compiler do you use?

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I have edited my original post with a complete example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Removing the register keywords does not change the problem. I use Debian Stretch, gcc and I compile in O0 mode.

Comment: @Jean-PierreCoffe Alright, I tried your code, it blocked, and after some debugging spotted what should have been obvious from the start - there is a data race. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I already had a working solution that involved creating parallel regions inside the loop, however I did not spot the data race that you brilliantly remarked. Your solution gives way better speedups on my architecture than my prior working solution, maybe (probably?) because of the repetitive creation of a parallel region. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Note that `omp_get_max_threads()` evaluates to the maximum number of threads that might be assigned to any team executing a parallel region, but in general, you are not guaranteed to get that number of threads in a given parallel region.  Even if you request a specific number of threads via a `num_threads` clause to an OMP directive, you may still get fewer.  Although in your particular program, you *should* get the full number of threads, it's poor form to depend on that.

Instead, use `omp_get_num_threads()` inside the parallel region to determine how many threads are *actually* in the team executing the region.  I suggest also using `omp_get_thread_num()` to get the present thread's number within the team, which will allow you to schedule your loop iterations manually, as is most appropriate when the algorithm actually depends on how they are scheduled, as yours does.  Also, do make use of the fact that variables declared inside the parallel region are automatically private with respect to the threads executing that region.  Combined with declaring your variables in the narrowest scope, that will reduce the number of data-sharing clauses you require.

But none of that resolves your issue for me.  What *does* resolve it (after applying the above) is moving the omp parallel directive from before the `do` to between the `do` and its associated block.  This should be interpreted as calling for the block to be executed in parallel, but not the `do` itself.  And that should not be a problem for you, because you want a barrier at the end of each execution of the block anyway.  You also need a barrier between your two inner loop nests to avoid data races.

Putting all that together, plus a bit more reorganization, yields this, which works<sup>*</sup> for me:

```
void parallel_bubble_sort(uint64_t *T, const uint64_t size) {
    bool swapped;

    do {
        swapped = false;
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            register uint64_t swap;
            register int i;
            int n_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
            int thread_num = omp_get_thread_num();
            int chunk_size = size / n_threads;

            for (i = thread_num * chunk_size + 1;
                    i < (thread_num + 1) * chunk_size;
                    i++) {
                if (T[i - 1] > T[i]) {
                    swap = T[i - 1];
                    T[i - 1] = T[i];
                    T[i] = swap;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
            #pragma omp barrier

            if (i < size && T[i - 1] > T[i]) {
                swap = T[i - 1];
                T[i - 1] = T[i];
                T[i] = swap;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while(swapped);
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> It "works" to the (incomplete) extent to which the algorithm is correct.  The algorithm as written *is not* correct unless the array size is a multiple of the number of threads executing the parallel region.  My machine has 12 logical cores (6 physical), and 1024 is not a multiple of 6.  When I run the program above, then, I end up with a few trailing elements going unsorted.  Similar could happen on *any* machine, because, again, you're not in general certain to get the full number of cores your request.  Fixing that issue is left as an exercise.

Comment: There is a data race in the original code. You've resolved it by pushing the outermost loop outside the parallel region. This is bad for performance with smaller problem sizes when the overhead from creating a parallel region cannot be amortised over a lot of data processing. Yes, you need a barrier to resolve the data race, but barriers are way cheaper than starting parallel regions, even when the latter are implemented with thread pools. Also, no need for barriers between worksharing constructs without `nowait` (as in the OP's code) as there are implicit ones.

Comment: Acknowledged, @HristoIliev.  I presented the above, with its narrowing of the scope of the parallel region, after first attempting to resolve the issue with a barrier.  For whatever reason, my logic failed me in that attempt, and I didn't see the eminently reasonable solution you've now presented.

Comment: You make a good point though in your first part. Writing portable OpenMP code that adheres to the spec is hard. Fortunately, the defaults for most implementations are sane and it allows for a bit of leniency.

Comment: Indeed, I did not specify it but I only work with number of threads and input arrays that are powers of 2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The solution that I came up with prior to getting solutions here did involve moving the parallel clauses inside the do\while, however I did not realize it was because of a data race. Thank you for your insights